# how can i clear content of fileupload widget in gwt + IE?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, file-upload

I want to clear content of fileUpload widget. I used-

```
FileUpload file = new FileUpload();
file.getElement().setPropertyString("value", "");
```

but it only works in chrome and not in Internet Explorer8.
is there any other workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the *FileUpload* in a *FormPanel* and then reset the *FormPanel* to clear the value of *FileUpload*.

Example

```
final FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
formPanel.add(fileUpload);
Button button = new Button("Clear value");
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            formPanel.reset();

    }
});
```